# Assistance adjusting CSS font for desktop vs mobile. (without @media)

Tags: css, media-queries, font-size

Font issues.

I want to first off say I am not very experienced in this regard and I have been messing with my CSS file for a few days now, and it is becoming exhausting. I have already rearranged my containers to fit in one vertical line. I think I have it close to where I want it. I have different font sizes throughout the CSS as I was trying to see what difference it made on mobile, and I have not really seen any difference. I tried using @media, but was not seeing any difference, probably because of how my meta tag is set up. I set the width to 1024 as it was the only way I found to fit the page to mobile without messing up all the containers/tables. My website is [www.dfshowdown.com](http://www.dfshowdown.com), the particular page I am trying to work on is if you click the 'OPTIMIZER' button on the home page, then click the 'GENERATE' button on the next page, you will be redirect to the page I am trying to make font changes too. Mainly, I was first trying to adjust .lineup-info {, as on mobile, the text appears larger than anything else for some reason.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">`

this is my css file

```
    body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-image: url('909153.jpg');
            background-size: cover; /* Ensures the image covers the entire viewport */
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed; /* Keeps the image fixed while scrolling */
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size:16px;  
            color: #FFFFFF; /* Text color on top of the image */
    background-position: center center;
    height: 100vh;
        }
     
 .container {
     top:20px;
    right:20px;
    background-color: #000000; /* Choose your fallback color here */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9); /* Semi-transparent background for content */
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 165, 0, 1); /* Orange outer glow */
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 900px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
    position: relative;
   margin:0 auto;
   text-align: center;
   
    /* Set a minimum top position based on content height */
    

 }
    h1, h2 {
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFA500; /* Orange header color */
        font-size:19px;  
    }

    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-size:15px;    
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid #3D3D3D; /* Table border color */
        font-size:16px;
    }

    th, td {
        padding: 8px;
        font-size:16px;
      
    }

    th {
        background-color: #474747; /* Darker gray header color */
        color: #FFA500; /* Orange text color for headers */
        font-size:16px;
    }

    .lineup-info {
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 16px !important;
    }
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .lineup-info {
        font-size: 16px !important;
}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .lineup-info {
        font-size: 16px !important;
}
}
@media (max-width: 575px) {
    .lineup-info {
        font-size: 14px !important;
}
}
@media (max-width: 425px) {
    .lineup-info {
        font-size: 10px !important;
}
}
```